# Translation is not working in HTML placeholder it is working with English but doesn't work Hebrew

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-directive

I am creating a web application in AngularJS and using translation for English and Hebrew languages.

It is working with HTML tag like :

```
<label translate="addemployee.Name"> Name </label>
```

But doesn't work with placeholder:

```
<input type="text" translate placeholder="{{ 'addemployee.Name' | translate }}" name="firstName" ng-model="employee.name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
```

Note : placeholder shows value in English but in Hebrew it is showing a special character like: `&;#1458&;#1506&;#1463&;#1500&;`

Is there any way to resolve the issue?